# 'This site can’t be reached' (Very simple docker instruction)

Tags: docker, flask

Here is the problem: **When I open my browser and enters "172.17.0.2:5000", the site can't be reached.**

I simply followed the official instruction of [Simple Web Application README link](https://github.com/mmumshad/simple-webapp-flask)). The blow scripts are the series of its commands.

```
2  apt-get update
3  apt-get install -y python
4  apt-get install python-pip
5  ls
6  cat > /opt/app.py
7  vim opt/app.py
8  vi opt/app.py
9  apt-get install vim
10  vim opt/app.py
11  cd opt
12  FLASK_APP=app.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Here is my `app.py` content.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Welcome!"

@app.route('/how are you')
def hello():
    return 'I am good, how about you?'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

When I run the flask app, it shows,,,

```
root@65d11b14d00b:/# FLASK_APP=opt/app.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0

 * Serving Flask app "opt/app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

To get my internal docker ip address, docker inspect

```
"Networks": {
    "bridge": {
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        ...
```

I tried to change port number in `app.py`,, and many other things, but none of them worked.

---

Response to @Burhan,

```
➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
ee543a9ce1cb        ubuntu              "bash"              6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                            elastic_hodgkin
➜  ~ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 ubuntu
28c1c29b7452e97adae3111632a0b67a320a2c0289034b4c517b015e1ca98c18
➜  ~ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 elastic_hodgkin
Unable to find image 'elastic_hodgkin:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for elastic_hodgkin, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

It seems `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 ubuntu` worked. But I can't still access to `localhost:5000` or `172.17.0.2:5000`.

Comment: You need to go through a docker tutorial first. Your confusion comes from not understanding how docker works.

Comment: To build on that, it's highly likely an answer will involve `docker rm` your existing container and `docker run` it with new options.  If you build a custom image using a Dockerfile it will already have your application in it and you won't have lost any work.